# Removing the 'Return Space' inserted before input() - Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Good day all,

Beginner's question here. In Python 3.6, I want to use the input() function, but when I do, it automatically inserts a return space between the prompt and the previous print output. Here's an example :

Code

```
print('a')
letter = input('letter: ')
print(letter)
```

Actual Output

```
a

letter: b
b
```

Desired Output

```
a
letter: b
b
```

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this error. It works just fine for me

Comment: Are you on Windows? Are you running the code inside an IDE (if so, which one?), or in the command prompt? (The reason I ask: on Windows, newlines get converted from `\n` to `\r\n`. Which is fine, because the command prompt _wants_ `\r\n`. But the "fake terminal" console in some IDE that doesn't get used much on Windows, or only gets used on Windows with Python 2.x, or who knows what, might get confused by that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `end=` parameter. This will redefine what `print` appends. It looks like your string in question has a trailing newline in it and that isn't being reflected correctly in your editor.

```
print('a', end="")
letter = input('letter: ')
print(letter)
```

Comment: That results in a prompt like `aletter: `.

Comment: Try print('a', end="\n") instead. This should force the compiler to use just a single newline.

Comment: Thank you. 
It solved my problem. Would you know why I need to do that and @Rushabh Mehta (1st comment on my post) doesn't?

Comment: @ConradSelig Good catch...I wonder why that's not the default behavior for OP

Comment: I'm not sure, my compiler did not give me a double newline either. You shouldn't have to do this to get the output you expect...
Just for clarification, any string value can be entered into end=. Using "\n" says "One newline" which is actually the default. Glad we got it to work anyways! KarlEmm you should accept @Dyno's answer :)

Comment: Right. Perhaps he has a non-conventional newline pasted after his string.

Comment: @ConradSelig I'm using Spyder. Could this be the cause?

Comment: Maybe, I don't have any experience with that, maybe another question would be a good idea.